# Python - Web Scraping :How to access div tag of 1 class when I am getting data for div tags for multiple classes

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want div tag of 2 different classes  in my result.
I am using following command to **scrape** the data  -
'''

```
result = soup.select('div', {'class' : ['col-s-12', 'search-page-text clearfix row'] })
```

'''

Now, I have specific set of information in class 'col-s-12' and another set of information n class 'search-page-text clearfix row'
Now, I want to find children of only div tag with class - 'col-s-12'. When I am running below code, then it looks for children of both the div tags, since I have not specified anywhere which class I want to search

'''

```
for div in result:
    
     
    print(div)
    prod_name = div.find("a" , recursive=False)[0]    #should come from 'col-s-12' only
    prod_info  = div.find("a" , recursive=False)[0]   # should come from 'search-page-text clearfix row' only
```

'''

Example -
'''

```
<div class = 'col-s-12'>
       <a href = "some_link"> This is what I want or variable **prod_name** </a>
</div>
<div class = 'search-page-text clearfix row'> 
       <a>   This should be stored in variable **prod_info**     </a>
</div>
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for first `<a>` tag under tag with `class="col-s-12"` and then use `.find_next('a')` to search next `<a>` tag.

Note: `.select()` method accepts only CSS selectors, not dictionaries.

For example:

```
txt = '''<div class = 'col-s-12'>
       <a href = "some_link"> This is what I want or variable **prod_name** </a>
</div>
<div class = 'search-page-text clearfix row'>
       <a>   This should be stored in variable **prod_info**     </a>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

prod_name = soup.select_one('.col-s-12 > a')
prod_info = prod_name.find_next('a')

print(prod_name.get_text(strip=True))
print(prod_info.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
This is what I want or variable **prod_name**
This should be stored in variable **prod_info**
```